# C# Mysql Select with Textbox Text

Tags: c#, mysql, select

Im trying to select a row in mysql database using a textbox's text.
However when I use the following code I get an error.

```
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand(); //we create a command
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM info where id=" + textBox1.Text ;  //in commandtext, we write the Query
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  //execute the SELECT command, which returns the data into the reader

        while (reader.Read())  //while there is data to read
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reader["info"].ToString());
        }
```

It works fine with letters but when I try to use a question mark or anything like that i get the following error:

"Parameter '?' must be defined."

Comment: can you post the exception??

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled
     HResult=-2147467259
     Message=Parameter '?' must be defined.
     Source=MySql.Data
     ErrorCode=-2147467259

Comment: With the current condition, your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. I urge you to consider using `parameter`s as given in the answers below.

Comment: Hold up, what or where are you putting this '?' ? And WHY do you have it?

Comment: Im putting this ? in my textbox, I have it because I need to grab data from a columm that has a ? in it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM info where id=" + textBox1.Text ;
```

Use this

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM info where id=@id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Always best practice.

Answer (score 0):

you better use parameters in this case

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM info where id=@id";
```

then you need to set the parameter value

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@id, textBox1.Text);
```

full code:

```
   string queryString="SELECT * FROM info where id=@id";
   using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
   using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection))
   {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something ...
            }
        }
    }
```

update :

change your parameter value setting line as below

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working how would I add your code into my existing? Here is my code I have at the moment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k87zcCn9

Comment: @user3540727 you need to set parameter value as `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);`

Comment: When I do this nothing gets returned from the database.

Comment: do you have column nameed 'id' in your info table? what is the column data type?

Comment: Yes I do, although I changed where id= to where string=, because I renamed id to string. The data type is TEXT. The info column Is also TEXT.